# Upgrading Graphics Card on ASUS CM6870-US015S

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, upgrade, power-supply

I want to upgrade my Graphics card(NVIDIA GT 620) on my computer(ASUS CM6870-US015S) and I have a couple of questions.

I noticed that the PSU on my Graphics card is only 350W so I'm assuming that I will have to upgrade that.

After a little searching I decided upon [Corsair CX-750](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0092ML0OC) with 600W and the [EVGA GeForce GTX760](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00DHW4HXY).

I was wondering if the above mentioned hardware will work well with my comptuter and if there will be any issues with my motherboard or anything else. I am aware that this will void my warranty but I just want a powerful computer.

Am I missing anything so far? I have to add that I intend to use multiple monitors at 1920x1200

Also would I have to add any cooling if I make this upgrade (Don't intend to overclock just yet)

My System Specifications are

- Processor: Intel Core i7-3770
- GPU : Nvidia GT-620
- Expansion Slots:2 x PCI-e x 1, 2 x PCI-e x 16
- Power Supply: 350W
- I couldn't find the exact motherboard model. The only thing I could find in System Information is System Model: CM6870

Comment: It may work, since the boards are a year apart. Beware of asking for product recommendations, as those questions become obsolete quickly and as such are not welcome here (delete the 6th paragraph and you're fine). Can you provide a detailed list of the hardware you have in your machine?

Comment: Thanks Doktoro, I didn't know that. I got rid of the product recommendation and added my system specs.

Comment: There's no reason why they shouldn't work - I've seen folk install 600 series nvidia cards on old core 2s. I don't see any possible issues here. The video card should probably be able to handle its own cooling in your average desktop, and that seems to be a large, reasonably designed case.